# Storing Output to Variable and Printing Output Later

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am having trouble with a piece of my code. I want to store an output statement to a variable. I want to put it outside the `for loop` so it outputs the statement at the end of my code rather than inside the loop. Is this possible. This is what I tried but I only get one output where multiple statements should be outputting.

```
outputs=[]
if Year in mydict and data_location in mydict[Year]:  
    busses_in_year = mydict[Year]
    #print("Here are all the busses at that location for that year and the new LOAD TOTAL: ")
    #print("\n")

    #Busnum, busname,scaled_power read from excel sheet matching year and location

    for busnum,busname,scaled_power in busses_in_year[data_location]:
        scaled_power= float(scaled_power)
        busnum = int(busnum)
        output='Bus #: {}\t Area Station: {}\t New Load Total: {} MW\t'
        formatted = output.format(busnum, busname, scaled_power)
        outputs.append(formatted)

        psspy.bsys(1,0,[0.0,0.0],0,[],1,[busnum],0,[],0,[])
        psspy.scal_2(1,0,1,[0,0,0,0,0],[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0])
        psspy.scal_2(0,1,2,[0,1,0,1,0],[scaled_power,0.0,0,-.0,0.0,-.0,0])
        psspy.fdns([0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0])


else:
    exit

print(formatted)
```

Comment: Why are you printing `formatted` instead of `outputs`? `outputs` is the list of all your formatted output strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

absolutely.

First, you're printing `formatted`, not your `outputs`

Then to print all of the outputs on seperate lines:

`print('\n'.join(outputs))`

What does that do? str.join takes an iterable collection (a list) and puts the string in-between them.  so `'X'.join(['a','b','c'])` results in `'aXbXc'`

Answer (score 1):

I know this sounds simple, but where you are doing this:

```
print(formatted)
```

You should be doing this:

```
print(outputs)
```

Or iterating over your list and printing each one individually.

```
for line in outputs:
  print(line)
```

Comment: just want to highlight that in Python 3 the parenthesis for `print()` is necessary

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to print each statement on a new line rather than having each statement next to each other: For example:`['Bus #: 126688\t Area Station: Buchanan\t New Load Total: 125.0 MW\t', 'Bus #: 126695\t Area Station: Millwood West\t New Load Total: 85.0 MW\t', 'Bus #: 126696\t Area Station: Ossining West\t New Load Total: 77.0 MW\t'] `

Comment: You may want to add a newline ('\n') to the beginning or end of each entry, too.

@chowsai, Thanks for that. I am kind of used to 2.7 :P